# JavaFX WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN firing before window actually shown

Tags: javafx

The real reason I'm trying to do this is to run a game (infinite) loop when the UI shows, but this shows the same problem.

```
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    primaryStage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, event -> {
        System.out.println("Shown");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    primaryStage.show();
```

This code will result in a console message, then a 4 second wait, then the window actually shows.  I can't really find anything on this and it doesn't seem to make much sense since the documentation for WINDOW_SHOWN specifically states it fires just after the window is shown.

Comment: Surely the problem is that you are blocking the FX Application Thread, thereby preventing the stage from being rendered (regardless of the semantics of whether it is really "showing" or not).

Comment: Never call `Thread.sleep` on the JavaFX application thread, just don't do it...all it will do is hang your UI.

Comment: "The real reason I'm trying to do this is to run a game (infinite) loop when the UI shows" => you don't show that code, but if you are running that code on the JavaFX application thread then it will have the same effect of freezing the UI as your `Thread.sleep` call.  I'm guessing your question here is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to the original question but a comment as to what solved a problem whose search brought me here.

I had a need to display an APPLICATION_MODAL custom dialog fired off by a MainScene show event hook.

If I displayed the dialog via *showAndWait()* the parent stage window decorations never completed rendering correctly until the dialog closed. 
 If I displayed the dialog via *show()* the parent rendered correctly yet I still had correct modal event-queue blocking that I needed.